# how to find params startswith string

Tags: groovy

I got an array:

```
params = [employer0=abc,employer1=def,employer2=,employer3=]
```

I want to find params that start with employer. Here's my code

```
params.findall {it.startsWith('employer')}.each{}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You miss an Upper A in findAll method :

```
params = ['employer0','employer1','employer2','employer3']​;
params.findAll {it.startsWith('employer')}.each{}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below code here: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/

```
def params = ['employer0=abc','employer1=def','employer2=','employer3=']

def results = params.findAll {it.startsWith('employer')}.each{}

println results
```

It gives : [employer0=abc, employer1=def, employer2=, employer3=]

I think you need to pass the values in params as string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
List employerParams = params.findAll{it.key.startsWith('employer')};
```

Comment: `params` is a list not a map. so there is no `it.key`